# Grant all users Access to an SSRS 2005 Report in SharePoint 2007 Integrated mode

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, active-directory, sharepoint-2007

All users on our in our domain have read access to the SharePoint Site and the Datasources folder.

We have some reports and report folders we want all users to have access to, so we tried granting execute and read to domain\domain users and NT Authority\Network Service, but they can't access the report unless we grant the specific user that access or grant an AD Group or Distribution List they are in access.

What's up with this?  Anyway to grant all users access to an SSRS report report through SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 1):

Try `NT Authority\Authenticated Users`

Comment: That's in there too. Did not help.